# Can .htaccess do different things based on {HTTP:Content-Length}?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I have a server that accepts HTTP POSTs from an 3rd Party, then returns either a 200 or 500.

The 3rd Party is not under my control, and sometimes sends very large POSTs, e.g. 40MB.

These POSTs cause my PHP code to run out of memory, which I can't catch, and so apache sends a 500.

The API retries that POST forever, and doesn't send new data, so this is a problem.

I've tried various things, but have ended up thinking that if I could have .htaccess just return a 200 and do nothing else, if the content_length was > X, then this would at least buy me time to restructure how this works.

So…

Is it possible to write a rule in .htaccess such that if content_length > X, it returns a 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the idea of faking an "everything OK" when it's not. Depending on your environment, you might have multiple approaches:

1. Increase the memory PHP may use in general (`php_value memory_limit 100M` in `.htaccess` or similar in `php.ini`
2. Increase the memory PHP may use only for this client. Try something like this (untested, `192.168.1.0/24` is the address of the remote system(s)):

   ```
   <If "-R '192.168.1.0/24'">
         php_value memory_limit 100M
   </If>
   ```
3. Use your idea if all else fails, something like this:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Length} -ge 200000 
   RewriteRule ^ - [R=200]
   ```

   This is also untested and unlikely to work as is, but the core of it is the `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Length}` part.

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same - in this case it is kinda a 200 case though because the POST data we expect is very small, so when we get these, they contain data that we don't want to process (Basically large jpgs base 64 encoded - we only care about the text content, so these aren't interesting anyway), so I'm not too unhappy about saying "Yep, thanks for that", then dumping their content behind my back while smiling at them!

Comment: Thanks - seems `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Length} >200000` does the trick, `-ge` didn't work, even though documentation says that it will…

Comment: "`-ge 200000`" - there should be no space between `-ge` and `200000` (it is a prefix operator). Strictly speaking `>200000` is a _lexicographical string comparison_, so you wouldn't necessarily expect this to work ("3" > "2000000" would be _true_ in most other languages) - except that it does. (?!) Apache appears to take the length of the string into consideration... `zz >bbb` is false, but `zza >bbb` is true. (?)